# Wrong path for "Custom Template Directory"?

Tags: wordpress, custom-templates, paths

I use CiviCRM with WordPress.  I previously migrated my site from Drupal.

I noticed today that my "Custom Template Directory", shown in Admin->Settings->Directories, is set to `[cms.root]/sites/all/civicrm_templates`.  This path doesn't exist, and it looks like a holdover from Drupal-style paths.

What should this typically be set to in a WordPress installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question to answer would be did you actually have any custom templates in sites/all/civicrm_templates and did you copy them over somewhere, since custom templates is an older override mechanism that still works but is a bit discouraged (use extensions instead).

Normally this path in blank in a fresh install, even for drupal.

If you did have files, then it depends where you copied them to, but it sounds like you didn't.

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't know that was an old mechanism, I don't have any custom templates, so I'll just blank out that field.